# Validate JSON field against enum

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, enums, jackson

I am constructing my `POJO` directly from the received `JSON` using `Jackson's ObjectMapper`. For that purpose I annotate my fields (in this case fields are abstract methods because I'm using AutoValue to reduce boilerplate) with `@JsonProperty` annotations.

Now, some of the fields in my POJO are `enums`, where JSON obviously contains a regular string. I would like to somehow validate that those JSON fields do indeed submit to the given enum type **before the object is constructed**.

Here is the example.

```
@JsonProperty(value = "messageType")
public abstract Optional<MessageType> messageType();
```

This property is of type `enum MessageType`, and the corresponding JSON field is ie. "messageType": "A_1" which is a string.

Now, if the "messageType" is something like "blabla" I'd like the validation to fail.

Is there any way to validate that with annotations using Hibernate Validator?

Comment: What is the current response you recieved when passed with the value not bound to the enum messageType? As far as Jackson library it reject the request and tell preceisely with the validation fail message.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to require separate validation? Jackson databinder will indicate the problem and you could catch exception and with newer versions of Jackson get more information on exact nature of problem.

And if you wanted more elaborate (or manual) checking you could declare setter that takes `java.lang.String` but you would use code of your own design to check and convert into actual field. That way you could indicate problem with even more specific exception (subtype of `IOException`) that caller could process.

Answer (score 1):

> @JsonProperty(value = "messageType")
>   public abstract Optional messageType();

Assumed you have, MessageType as enum with distinct values A_1, A_2...

Create a static utility method to serialize/deserialize for the enum values from the received/sent json values

```
public static <T extends Enum<T>> T getEnumFromJson(Class<T> enumClass, String value) 
{
  if(enumClass == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("EnumClass value can't be null");
  for(Enum<?> enumValue : enumClass.getEnumConstants()){
      if(enumValue.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(value)){
         return (T) enumValue;
      }
  }
//Validation message construct to give more meaningful details to end-user
  StringBuilder erroMsg = new StringBuilder();
  boolean bFirst = true;
  for(Enum<?> enumValue : enumClass.getEnumConstants()) {
   errorMessage.append(bFirst ? "": ", ").append(enumValue);
   bFirst = false;
  }

  throw new IllegalArgumentException(value + " is invalid value, Supported value are "+ errorMessage);
}

//Enum as represented below
public enum MessageType {
  A_1,
  A_2,
  A_3

  @JsonCreator
  public static MessageType fromValue(String value){
    return getEnumFromJson(MessageType.class, value);
  }

  @JsonValue
  public String toJson(){
    return name().toLowerCase();
  }

}
```